# UnauthorizedAccessException while saving an image file in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: canvas, windows-phone-8.1, file-writing

I'm trying to use the following code to save the contents of myCanvas as an image file in the gallery (for Windows Phone 8.1, not Silverlight). When I run the app and call SaveFileToPhone(), it throws System.UnauthorizedAccessException. 

I have already checked the Capabilities in the Manifest file and they seem to be fine. What am I doing wrong. I've read through a lot of resources but couldn't find a solution, Please Help!

I'm still a noob and I tried using the code I found online.

```
 public async void SaveFileToPhone()
      {
          var file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileAsync("bug.jpeg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
          var outStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
          await SaveVisualElementToFile(myCanvas, file);
          outStream.Dispose();
      }


 async Task SaveVisualElementToFile(FrameworkElement element, StorageFile file)
        {
            string fileName = "customphoto.jpg";
            var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element, (int)element.Width, (int)element.Height);
            var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await
                    BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
                byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                     BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                     (uint)element.Width, (uint)element.Height,
                                     96, 96, bytes);

                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
```

> - $exception  {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>     task) at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>     task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>     at
>     ChoosersLaunchers8._1.PhotoChooser.d__1e.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>     task)    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>     task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>     at
>     ChoosersLaunchers8._1.PhotoChooser.d__17.MoveNext()
>     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__3(Object
>     state)    at
>     System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()}    System.Exception
>     {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be opening the StorageFile twice which isn't allowed. Don't open the file before calling your SaveVisualElementToFile method since you are opening the file in that method already.

Also you wouldn't need the outstream.dispose since the file would be automatically disposed with the "using" statement in your method.

Comment: Thank You! Removing 
`var outStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);`
did the trick.

Comment: But now a new issue has cropped up, the `encoder.SetPixelData` throws the following when I try to run the code.
_System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range._ 
What could be the issue?

Comment: You are getting that error because you probably didn't specify a canvas width and height.

Comment: You're right. I fixed the Height & Width of my Canvas and now the code works! Images are being saved to the gallery, but the image is distorted and glitchy. I think this is due to incorrect DPI values. I have uploaded the resultant image and the expected result [here](http://s4.postimg.org/bcefu2w7h/App_Result.png).